# Water wave packet variance

Tags: waves, fourier-transform

Consider the following quantity,

$$I = \int  x^2|\eta(x)|^2 \ dx,$$.

For $\eta(x)$ a solution to some linear equation, we have

$\eta(x) = \int a(k) e^{ikx} \ dk$ 
where, for $\eta$ to be real, we have $a(-k) = a^*(k)$.

Therefore, the integral $I$ becomes

$$I = \int\int a(k)a^*(k')\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{i(k-k')x}\ dx\right) \ dk dk'$$.

Now, the term in parenthesis can be found to be $-\delta''(k-k')$ where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function and primes are differentiation w.r.t $k$. Therefore, $I$ becomes

$$I=-\int a(k')\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial k^2} a(k)\right) \ dk$$.

Now, consider a wave packet defined as $$a(k) =S/k\quad k\in(k_o-dk/2,k_o+dk/2),$$
and zero otherwise, $S$ is a constant, $dk$ is the bandwidth and $k_o$ is some central wavenumber.

Now, if I substitute this into the last equation for $I$, this yields a negative number, which is absurd since $I$ is a positive definite integral.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your third equation, I think you have $$I=\int \bar{a}(k)\bigl(-\Delta_k\bigr) a(k) dk\; ,$$ where I have rewritten the second derivative as the [Laplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) operator and corrected tha missing complex conjugate and the fact that you have only one variable.

Said that, this can be rewrittenas the scalar product in $L^2$:
$$I= \langle a, -\Delta_k a\rangle =\lVert \partial_k a\rVert^2$$
that is always positive.

A simpler way of seeing that is:
$$I=\int x^2\lvert\eta(x)\rvert^2dx <+\infty \Rightarrow \lVert x \eta(x)\rVert_{L^2}< +\infty$$
i.e. $x\eta(x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Now the Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ is [unitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem) on $L^2$, i.e. preserves the norm, and $\mathscr{F}[x\eta(x)]=-i\partial_k \mathscr{F}[\eta](k)$. So you obtain the equality:
$$\lVert x \eta(x)\rVert_{L^2_x}^2=\lVert \mathscr{F}[x \eta(x)](k)\rVert_{L^2_k}^2=\lVert -i\partial_k \mathscr{F}[\eta](k)\rVert_{L^2_k}^2=\lVert\partial_k a(k)\rVert_{L^2_k}^2$$
with your notation of the Fourier transform of $\eta$.